# Is it possible for Dotfuscator and ILMerge to work together?

Tags: c#, .net, ilmerge, dotfuscator

I'm trying to get Dotfuscator to work with ILMerge, but whichever order I apply them it always breaks somehow:

- When I use dotfuscator and then ILMerge I am getting a message the the pdb database is old.
- When I do vice-versa dotfuscator would simply throw an error saying that there are no assemblies to build.

How can I get Dotfuscator to play well with ILMerge?

Comment: edit: when I use dotfuscator and then ilmerge - i am getting a message the the pdb database is old? and when i do vice-versa dotfuscator would simply throw an error saying that there are no assemblies to build? And...yes, using just one of them works. Plus, all assemblies are totally managed code I am not trying to merge c++ with c#.

Comment: When you are using ILMerge first and then dotfuscator, are you sure you are passing the correct assembly name, i.e the output of ILMerge.

Answer (score 3):

The commercial version of Dotfuscator contains a feature called Linking, which does the same thing as ILMerge. If you have the commercial version, I highly recommend you use Linking.

If you are using the Community Edition, I would recommend merging your assemblies first with ILMerge, and then taking that output assembly and adding it as an input in your Dotfuscator project. There should be no issues with this scenario. If you try this and are still having problems, please post a thread on the [PreEmptive support forums](http://www.preemptive.com/forum/) and I will be happy to assist you in getting things working.

Answer (score 1):

Use ILMerge and then Dotfuscator.

What version of ILMerge?
What is the command line you are using?
What is the exact error message you receive?